# Как сделать что-то похожее на книжку?

Tags: html, css

Есть такая фигурка - **Форма белого квадрата**
Подскажите как реализовать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что конкретно вам не удаеться реализовать?

Comment: Форму белого квадрата

Comment: Что-то он не очень квадрат...

Comment: Его просто помнули)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно еще проще.

```css
.book {
    background-color:pink;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    margin:50px;
}

.book:before, .book:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:inherit;
    z-index:-1;
}

.book:before {transform:skewY(10deg);}

.book:after  {transform:skewY(-10deg);}
```

```html
<div class="book">book</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можна через `::before` и `::after` довабить два треугольника

```css
body{
background:#999;}
.kwadrat{
position:relative;
width:150px;
height:150px;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:2;
}
.kwadrat p{
font-size:24px;
color:white;
text-align:center;
padding-top:40px;
position:relative;
z-index:99;}
.kwadrat::before{
content:'';
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
right:0;
 border-top: 75px solid transparent;
 border-right: 175px solid red;
 border-bottom: 75px solid transparent;
  z-index:0;
}
.kwadrat::after{
content:'';
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
 border-top: 75px solid transparent;
 border-left: 175px solid red;
 border-bottom: 75px solid transparent;
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="kwadrat">
  <p>Portfolio</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот ещё вариант

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
#triangle1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 70px solid transparent;
    border-left: 240px solid white;
    border-bottom: 70px solid transparent;
}
#triangle2 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 70px solid transparent;
    border-right: 240px solid white;
    border-bottom: 70px solid transparent;
}
#text {
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 60px solid transparent;
  border-left: 90px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
    <div id="triangle1"></div>
    <div id="triangle2"></div>
    <div id="text">portfolio</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще вариант, без псевдоэлементов, одной лишь рамочкой, но не очень гибкий в плане изменения размеров контента.

```css
    .angle4 {
        position: relative;
        height: auto;
        width: 0;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 30px 150px;
        border-color: transparent #f0f;
    }

    .wrap {
        position: relative;
        margin-left: -100px;
        margin-right: -100px;
        padding: 45px 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<div class="angle4">
    <div class="wrap">Какой-то текст</div>
</div>
```